# Is there a way to get a propertiesUrl from Autodesk Forge's Model Properties API that is not pre-signed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, webrequest, autodesk-bim360

I am writing a Dynamo script to extract the properties out of all of the models in my modelset in BIM 360. Some of the files (notably the ones with more objects) will give me a pre-signed propertiesUrl value that looks like this:

[https://bim360-nucleus-production-us-east-1-temporary-index.s3.amazonaws.com/36174d28-fbd6-4146-a3af-3f3a7bb8ec52/index/v2/indexes/5JAa5g6Nk-t5KQsgFe5OJA/properties.ldjson.gz?X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Security-Token={{token_value}}-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={{Credential_value}}/20220509/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220509T223945Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature={{Amz_Signature_Value}}](https://bim360-nucleus-production-us-east-1-temporary-index.s3.amazonaws.com/36174d28-fbd6-4146-a3af-3f3a7bb8ec52/index/v2/indexes/5JAa5g6Nk-t5KQsgFe5OJA/properties.ldjson.gz?X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Security-Token=%7B%7Btoken_value%7D%7D-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=%7B%7BCredential_value%7D%7D/20220509/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220509T223945Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=%7B%7BAmz_Signature_Value%7D%7D)

This pre-signed URL has been troublesome because it will expire within 60 seconds of being issued and Dynamo is having trouble making the requests on time, or because I will get a network transport error when using the DynaWeb package (only 1/3 requests are made successfully):

[Dynaweb Network Transport Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJG6E.png)

When I try using Dynamo's OOTB node "Web Request", it will give me values that contain characters that aren't even close to what the response should be.

[Dynamo Web Request OOTB Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Rw8.png)

Is there a way to circumvent the need for a pre-signed url for the "propertiesUrl" endpoint? I can't find anything in the API in how to download the properties from the indices besides what is detailed here (which shows how to get properties with a Bearer token, but not how to opt out of a pre-signed url format):
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/index-v2-index-properties-get/

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/index/v2/projects/cd743656-f130-48bd-96e6-948175313637/indexes/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d/properties'  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'
```

Comment: firstly, sorry for letting you wait. It looks the signed url you pasted comes from Index v1 API of Model Coordination. While the last url you mentioned is the new API (Model Properties API). The new API is also called index v2 API. It is an general API to get model properties, without generating signed url in front end. you only call the endpoint to get properties. So are you actually talking about the latter ?

Comment: Yes, I used the v2 API and it still gives me pre-signed URLs. I was, however, able to just reconstruct a URL for the properties based on the URL structure from my other requests that didn't have a pre-signed URL, and that worked great.

Comment: glad to know it works now. I am still curious why V2 API returns pre-signed url to front end directly. if you could share how you called the endpoint, I'd like to take a look. Thank you.

Comment: `import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("developer.api.autodesk.com")
payload = json.dumps({
  "query": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$count": "s.views"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': bearer_token,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
conn.request("POST", "/construction/index/v2/projects/"+container_id+"/indexes/@@@@@/queries", payload, headers)
    
    
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
    
OUT = (data.decode("utf-8"))`